# Create an empty CD-ROM image and inject/extract files into/from it using Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cd

Using Java I need to be able to create an empty CD image and also to inject/extract files into/from this image. Do you know any java libs for that? Is there a way to accomplish it without using JNI? (**if not**, then your JNI solution is appreciated). Thank you guys.

PS. This task is required for data transportation between emulated environment created by Qemu emulator.

Answer (score 1):

In principle this is simple to implement, just write a file that is properly structured as CD-image. In practice thats probably a lot of work.

Simply googling for "java create iso image" reveal there is already an implementation to do just that: http://jiic.berlios.de/

Comment: For you awareness, that link is broken.