# Creating an 'image' of a disk with null files

Tags: java, image, file, tree, iso

I am attempting to create something like an iso of the hard drive of a computer in java, but with no data in the files. Like a file tree, but an iso. This happens on client A. 
The point of this is to transfer this ISO file tree over GAE to another client (Let's say client B) who should be able to mount the iso on his computer using windows explorer.

The above is what I want to achieve - I know it is very specific, sorry about this. However, all I want to know is how to create an ISO (or some other mountable image of a hard drive) that contains no data in the files.

No data in the files = the files are still there (I must be able to see the names of the files), but they are empty. You know. Open them with notepad and all you get is "" in the file. Or a space. Whatever. The point is to make the iso small in size so I can transfer into to client B, instead of transfering the whole hard drive. After this client B can choose the file he wants to fetch of the other computer, but that's a different story.

**The question:**

How to create something like an ISO of the hard drive of a computer in Java, but with no data in the files?

Feel free to recommend a solution that has the same functionality but takes a different approach.

**Update:**

Stuffed the ISO approach. Created an object with lots of trees of files. Contact me somehow if u want to do the same.

Comment: No data in files. But how many no data file would be there? [Related Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621227/create-an-empty-cd-rom-image-and-inject-extract-files-into-from-it-using-java) with a relevant answer.

Comment: ooh wow, a response. lol. Bit confused by the question. The idea was to have **all** the files on the hard drive in the image - otherwise the thing would be pretty useless.

Comment: *"Thankyou for reading through!"*  Thanks for adding a specific question.  Wait.. what is your question?

Comment: I added it in at the end for clarification then. Sorry if I was unclear haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to copy the entire file structure with empty files:

```
// you may want to actually handle the IOException rather than just throwing it
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  makeFileStructure(new File("someDirectory"), "someDestinationDirectory");
}

static void makeFileStructure(File src, String dest) throws IOException
{
  for (File f: src.listFiles())
  {
     String newPath = dest + File.separatorChar + f.getName();
     if (f.isDirectory())
     {
        if (!new File(newPath).mkdirs())
           // you may want to handle this better
           throw new IOException("Directory could not be created!");
        makeFileStructure(f, newPath);
     }
     else
        new File(newPath).createNewFile();
  }
}
```

Just make sure `"someDestinationDirectory"` isn't a subdirectory of `"someDirectory"`, otherwise things will obviously not go very well.

Pretty sure you'll need an external library for creating an ISO image (if you want to create it). Try [Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+create+iso+file). But it might be easier to just do it with an external application and [a batch file](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch+file+create+iso) (after having run the above code).

Comment: Thankyou very much for this :D. Now I need to figure out how to create an ISO of a specific folder, although hopefully this shouldn't be too hard (https://github.com/stephenc/java-iso-tools or JIIC). I would upvote but don't have enough rep lol